# Extending Rancher's Auth-service to use other (OAuth) provider

Tags: authentication, go, docker, oauth, rancher

Our team is currently looking to use Rancher for a Docker container orchestration solution, and one the things I'm looking to do is try setting up Access Control on the Rancher server using a provider that isn't supported by Rancher at the moment (this being [Fiware Lab](https://account.lab.fiware.org/) which can be a OAuth provider).

Rancher handles authentication in a separate Golang service available in [this repo](https://github.com/rancher/rancher-auth-service). This could be extended to allow for a new provider for authentication as described in the wiki of the repo. What I'm confused about however is how I could then deploy my extended service with Rancher Server. Is it possible to just run the extended service without having to build a new Docker image for Rancher Server altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an external service mainly to make it easier for us to develop additional providers, and to pull that code out of the Cattle core (the migration of which is on-going, only Github is moved and Shibboleth was added as a new one only into the Golang one).

While it is possible, this is not currently a general public plugin point. There is not any formal way to register your own provider, get that into the server container, provide UI to configure it, or log into it once configured.